# Fetch the column names per row in a dataframe that are not NaN-values (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe that has several features and a feature can have a NaN-value. E.g.

```
feature1    feature2    feature3   feature4
  10           NaN          5          2
  2            1            3          1
  NaN          2            4          NaN
```

Note: the columns can also contain strings.

How could we get a list/array per row that contains the column name of non NaN-values?

Thus the result array of my example would be:

```
res = array([feature1, feature3, feature4], [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4], 
[feature2, feature3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For improve performance use list comprehension with convert values to numpy array:

```
c = df.columns.to_numpy()
res = [c[x].tolist() for x in df.notna().to_numpy()]
print (res)
[['feature1', 'feature3', 'feature4'], 
 ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4'], 
 ['feature2', 'feature3']]
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
    

In [28]: %%timeit
    ...: out = (df.stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1']
    ...:          .agg(list).to_numpy().tolist()
    ...:        )
    ...:        
    ...: 
96.5 ms ± 8.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [29]: %%timeit
    ...: c = df.columns.to_numpy()
    ...: res = [c[x].tolist() for x in df.notna().to_numpy()]
    ...: 
3.36 ms ± 185 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: with this solution, I get an index error: "IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 648 but corresponding boolean dimension is 33". The shape of my df is (648, 33).

Comment: @Steven01123581321 - Do you convert `.to_numpy()` ?

Comment: yes., first to numpy and then the list comprehension.

Comment: @Steven01123581321 - what is `print (len(df.columns))` ? It is `33` ?

Comment: I was trying both methods at the same time and I think that's why it didn't work.  My bad. This works just fine! +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to keep only the non-NAN values, and aggregate as list with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = df.stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1'].agg(list)
```

Output as Series:

```
level_0
0              [feature1, feature3, feature4]
1    [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4]
2                        [feature2, feature3]
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

As lists:

```
out = (df.stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1']
         .agg(list).to_numpy().tolist()
       )
```

Output:

```
[['feature1', 'feature3', 'feature4'],
 ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4'],
 ['feature2', 'feature3']]
```